# Increment and decrement in while loops

Tags: c, while-loop, increment

This is the type of code I'm having trouble with, just an example:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #define TEN 10
 int main(void)
 {
     int n = 0;
     while (n++ < TEN)
         printf("%5d", n);
     printf("\n");
     return 0;
 }
```

here, the increment operator works inside the while loop first, and n gets 1; and then it works again printf() statement for the while loop, so that now n gets 2 and the first time the printf() statement is executed "1" is printed? because otherwise, "0" would have been printed. I'm not sure if it does work this way,so could you please explain this, like am I correct?
PS: I ain't got a teacher, so I'm asking you guys...

Comment: `n` is incremented *after* compared, but *before* printed. BTW, you can get a "teacher" here: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/c-programming

Comment: Try to find a good book, it should explain exactly how the prefix and suffix `--` and `++` operators work.

Comment: `#define TEN 10` is silly; `#define MAX 10` or something similar would be more sensible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick here is the `++` postfix operator: it is called post-incrementation. The value used in the expression if the value of `n` **before** the increment and `n` is updated at some point before the next sequence point, either the end of the expression, a function call or a comma operator, an advanced operator you are unlikely to need anytime soon.

Another caveat is the peculiar handling of boolean values in C: comparisons such as `n < 10` evaluate to `1` if they are true and `0` otherwise. Conversely, tests without a comparison (such as `if (n)` succeed for any non-zero, non-null and non-NaN values.

Here is the sequence of events:

- `int n = 0` defines and initializes a local variable `n` of type `int` to the value `0`.
- `while (n++ < TEN)` : `n` is compared to `TEN`, the result is true (`1` in C) since `0 < 10` **then** `n` is incremented and gets the value `1`. The result of the comparison is true hence the `while` loop proceeds to its commanded statement.
- `printf("%5d", n);` prints the value of `n`, which is `1`.
- execution proceeds to the loop test.
- `while (n++ < TEN)` : `n` is compared again to `TEN`, the result is still `1` since `1 < 10` **then** `n` is incremented and gets the value `2`. The result of the comparison is true hence the `while` loop proceeds to its commanded statement.
- `printf("%5d", n);` prints the value of `n`, which is `2`. Note that there is no separator between this and the previous output nor the next.
- execution proceeds to the loop test.
- ... these steps are repeated until `9` is printed
- `while (n++ < TEN)` : `n` is compared to `TEN`, the result is `1` since `9 < 10` **then** `n` is incremented and gets the value `10`. The result of the comparison is still true because the comparison was performed before the increment hence the `while` loop proceeds to its commanded statement.
- `printf("%5d", n);` prints the value of `n`, which is `10`.
- execution proceeds to the loop test.
- `while (n++ < TEN)` : `n` is compared to `TEN`, the result is false (`0` in C) since `101 is not`< 10`**then**`n`is incremented and gets the value`11`. The result of the comparison is false hence the`while` loop stops and control skips to the next statement.
- `printf("\n");` prints a newline, ending the output line `12345678910`
- `return 0;` the `main` function returns with an exit status of `0` which means success.

Comment: Your use of `1` for a value of `true` is confusing. Too many 1s in this explanation. Remember your audience

Comment: True is non-zero and not 1 in C.

Comment: @RichardChambers: more precisely, true comparisons evaluate to `1` in C while booleans tests with `!` are true for non-zero, non-null and non-NaN values. My wording might be a little confusing, but is semantically correct. I added a paragraph to explain this C-ism.

Answer (score 0):

`n++` is a `post` increment. See standard `n1570` section `6.5.2.4`

> The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the operand. As
>   a side effect, the value of the operand object is incremented (that
>   is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to it).

```
while (n++ < TEN) /* 0 < 10 not 1 < 10 */ 
    printf("%5d", n);/* here incremented value gets printed */
```